# Angular 5.x page loading or initialisation of module itself taking longer time

Tags: angular

Total loading time is around 32.3 Seconds. This happening we are opening new tab from last page. This API takes around 240 ms to 10 seconds to get data. But before API calls UI modules loading itself taking longer time.

What will be major cause of this ?[image]

app-module.ts almost imported 91

respective component imported around 9 modules including basic ng modules.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setting aot=true working fine. There was lots of error and warning which causing issue. I used aot=false.

After running this

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

Its working fine and loading fast.

old way i am using, this was causing loading issue :

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

Answer (score 3):

Please do following things if it is not done in your application :
1) Build with --prod option to enable production build.
2) Use compressed and sprite images.
3) Lazy load all the modules based on each routing. Refer link https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
4) If you are using Angular universal then do the server side rendering, refer link https://angular.io/guide/universal
5) Separate your vendor.bundle.js from main.bundle.js by writing "vendor hunk" : true in your angular.json file

Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: #5 - added screenshot of how files get called. In my case main.bundle and vendor.bundle is already separated. for 1 point i have facing this issue in production only while doing --prod option. 2 point - in my case there is not images using its backoffice portal.

Comment: ng build --prod --aot works using this. First i have to solve all error and warning

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can reduce the loading time significantly:

1. Try to build with --prod option to enable production build.
2. Use Lazy Loading for modules

Comment: first option is not work. because already using the same. Let me try lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement source-map-explorer to view size of each js file and using sourcemaps, we can isolate the compiler from vendor.bundle.js. This helps in reducing the size of js file and hence loads page faster. This is the concept of AOT in Angular.